How do I skip the first and last SQL result?
I'm using https://sqlime.org/#demo.db so let's assume sqlite3 syntax. Though I'd be happy to hear about answers in other flavors of SQL.
I'm running the following query:
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10

How do I skip the first and last SQL result?
I know I can use OFFSET for dropping the first:
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1

But this is the only solution I came up with for dropping the last:
WITH data AS (SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1)
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1

So I'm sorting and skipping the first, and then reverse sorting and skipping the first. Which gives me what I want but just feels like there might be a more elegant solution. Anybody aware of a simpler way to do this?
Note that I could use LIMIT in theory for this purpose. But I don't know how many rows there are, and the LIMIT solution is only good when LIMIT is guaranteed to be limiting the result.

WITH data AS (
  SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum_asc,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rownum_desc 
  FROM employees
)
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE rownum_asc > 1 AND rownum_desc > 1;

Note if you have fewer than three employees, this query will give an empty result.

FWIW, SQLite has supported window functions since version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15).

LEAD(1) OVER (ORDER BY id) is a bit more efficient.

I think you can try the following:
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS first_id, MAX(id) AS last_id
    FROM employees
)
ORDER BY id ASC;

Let me know if it works!

SQLite returns error: Parse error: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1. This is because it's not valid to compare a single column id to a subquery that returns two columns. It would work if the subquery returns one column, by doing a UNION of one query that returns the MIN(id) and a second query that returns the MAX(id).

A slightly more efficient solution than @BillKarwin: using opposing row-numebrs is going to require a second sort, so instead use LEAD with the same sort and check for NULL.
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum_asc,
   LEAD(1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS is_not_last
  FROM employees
)
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE rownum_asc > 1
AND is_not_last = 1;


I don't use sqlite as often. I'm curious about using offset for one of the boundaries (see this: https://dbfiddle.uk/lbrufc5J )

@JoelCoehoorn Yes that seems to be a good option also. Maybe write an answer
